# Javascript and database, special symbols not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, database

I have a string that I took from a database and I get values like "JORG�", this should be like "JORGÉ", however I do not find a way to modify this. When I check the values in my database using dbeaver it also displays "JORG�". How can I modify this string in javascript, so it displays correctly?

Comment: maybe you have a look to [*funny symbols*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=funny+symbols)

Comment: I do not find the same issue...

Comment: If you do not have access to alter the db then sadly you cannot do anything about it. Your browser is capable of showing this characters but first it has to get the correct ones from db. If you can alter the db use utf32_general_ci encoding for that column

Comment: If dbeaver show is the wrong way, then the data is most likely already save wrong. You probably have the wrong encoding for the database connection or you send the data with the wrong encoding to your database. You really should fix the origin of that problem, then fix that data in your database instead of looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode utf8 when going to the DB, and decode utf8 when coming back if the MySQL table is in UTF8.

Comment: I use a Rest API to connect with database

Comment: Yes, you've to encode your data in utf8 format before inserting in your DB

Comment: @Y.Berrama That depends on the settings of the database and/or the adapter. The data has to be send in the encoding that is set for the connection, or the encoding used for the connection has to be changed. To say that the data as to be send in `uft8` in general is incorrect.

Comment: I fixed it by going into the python script that creates the REST API and instead of doing str(value), I do value.decode('unicode-escape')